# WPF C# INotifyPropertyChanged doesn't fire up

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I am building a WPF application that as part of its flow, checks for network connectivity and display the IP address in a TextBlock.

Now I am trying to update the TextBlock Text property everytime the IP address changes for whatever reason.

I have the IP address change working fine, but i could not get INotifyPropertyChanged to work.

I read all the possible solutions and implementations but I couldn't come up with a working code.

The public property gets the value from a static string from the Network Helper class.
So, the code:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
    }

       public string ipAddress
    {
        get { return NetworkStatus.localIP; }
        set
        {
            if (value != NetworkStatus.localIP)
            {
                NetworkStatus.localIP = value;

                NotifyIPChanged("IpAddress");
            }
        }
    }
    private void NotifyIPChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ipTxt"                            
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding DataContext.ipAddress}"   
                       Height="30" 
                       Width="110" 
                       Margin="-30,10,0,-10"
                       />
```

**UPDATE**
NetWorkStatus.cs -- static bool IsNetworkAvailable()
...

```
                            if (statistics.BytesReceived > 0 || statistics.BytesSent > 0)
                        {
                            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
                            localIP = host.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToString();
                            return true;
                        }
```

As you can see this method sets a static string "localIP". This is then evaluated by IpAddress property.

Why the TextBlock Text property doesn't get updated when the IP Address changes?

Comment: NotifyIPChanged("IpAddress"); should be NotifyIPChanged("ipAddress"); or even better NotifyIPChanged(nameOf(ipAddress)); or consider using CallerMemberName, and then you don't have to pass the name at all.

Comment: Rename the property to `IpAddress`, so that it adheres to widely accepted naming conventions. Besides that, `NotifyIPChanged` seems an odd name for a method that can fire the PropertyChanged event for any property name. Typical names for this method are `NotifyPropertyChanged`, `RaisePropertyChanged` or `OnPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Thank you for your semantic suggestions. I fixed them. Anyway application behaviour doesn't change. The handler doesn't fire up.

Comment: The Binding is also wrong. It should be `Text="{Binding IpAddress}"`, because the default source of the binding is already the current DataContext.

Comment: Did as Clemens suggested. Still no go. Really can't understand why.

Comment: You might be changing the property from a different thread which does not work well with WPF controls. Try wrapping it in `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => set property)`

Answer (score 1):

Rename the property to `IpAddress` so that it adheres to widely accepted naming conventions.

```
public string IpAddress
{
    get { return NetworkStatus.localIP; }
    set
    {
        if (value != NetworkStatus.localIP)
        {
            NetworkStatus.localIP = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Use the `CallerMemberName` attribute on the `propertyName` parameter of your notification method, so that you do not have to write the name explicitly.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
...

private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Bind it correctly. The current `DataContext` is already used as source object of the Binding. You must not add it to the property path.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding IpAddress}" ... />
```

---

In a possible next step you might want to separate the view from the view model and put the property in a separate class:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string IpAddress
    {
        get ...
        set ...
    }

    ...
}
```

and assign the Window's `DataContext` to an instance of the view model class:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your remarkings. I did that. But it doesn't get to work.

Comment: From what you've shown in your question there isn't much more to say. Try putting a breakpoint in the `IpAdress` getter to see if it gets hit. Check the value of `NetworkStatus.localIP`.

Comment: This is the problem. IpAddress get called at the Start of the application but it doesn't when the IP Change. The event that detects the IP change works correctly though. That is the main issue. Thanks for your support Clemens.

Comment: The setter of the IpAddress property must be called in order to notify about a change of that property. However, if there is some "event that detects the IP change" (which you haven't shown in your question), it may also call `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IpAddress))` directly.

Comment: So how exactly and from where do you set the ipAddress property of the MainWindow?

Comment: a static bool function in another static class evaluates the network change and then set a static string:                                localIP = host.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToString(); localIP than is evaluated from the ipAddress property.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant code parts. Obviously no PropertyChanged event is fired an no UI is updated when only `NetworkStatus.localIP` is changed, but the `IpAddress` setter isn't called.

Comment: Added as per your request.

Comment: It's a out of the scope of the original question, but you should declare a (static) event in your NetworkStatus class that is fired whenever the `localIP` value changes. The MainWindow would then register an event handler, which would call `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IpAddress))`.

Comment: Setting the NetworkStatus.localIP will not somehow automagically also set the ipAddress property of your MainWindow...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a closer look to how *WPF* works.
As a remark, there is no need to implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* in code behind. If you are using events, then you can automatically refresh the properties of the targeted UI element.

However, using code behind is not a good practice in our days. You should take a look at MVVM pattern. You have there a Model, View and ViewModel. The ViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

The fact is that your code is in my opinion absolutely wrong. The naming is not fine : when you implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* you should not implement it only for a property, and the name should not look like : **NotifyIPChanged**, instead you should use *RaisePropertyChanged*, *NotifyPropertyChanged*  or *OnPropertyChanged*. In setters you should not refresh something else, but only the property that you are targeting, because otherwise the *Single Responsability* principle is violated, as in your case. Also a bad practice is to bind to *Code Behind*.

I hope this post would make you to read more about MVVM and WPF. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

is it possible that the Event doesnt react, because the first letter of IpAdress is an Upper?

> NotifyIPChanged("**I**pAddress");
>
> public string ipAddress
>   Text="{Binding DataContext.**i**pAddress}"

Comment: That was a typo in the thread. I had it set correctly in my code.